# Performance comparison of dnxcore50 vs dnx451? (CoreClr vs .net Framework)

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, coreclr

I have tried to find some data on performance of these two targets compared, but did not succeed. I am interested in a asp.net5 web application that runs on Windows (Or azure web app e.g.). Is there any significant difference in performance or from that point of view the targets are roughly equal?

Answer (score 5):

As far as benchmarks are concerned, they can all be found on GitHub on [aspnet/benchmarks](https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks)

They even include the tools and procedure to run the benchmark yourself on your system.

So far, ASP.NET 4.6 is able to handle 57,843 requests per seconds. And ASP.NET 5 on Kestrel can handle 168,005 requests per seconds.

As for performance differences, you might be interested in all the bugs currently open:

- https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/labels/Perf
- https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/labels/performance
- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/labels/performance

Lots of work needs to be done before RTM.

Comment: That's nice page, thank you. This does not answer the question if ASP.NET 5 on Kestrel is faster on dnx or dnx core :)

Comment: Good news, you can run the test yourself on your environment! :P

Comment: I am OK with a generic test results from some other environment, but I really guess they are pretty much the same since it all boils down to jit-compiled code that should be the same or almost the same I guess.

Comment: added some links to performance issues that you can check if it helps you

Comment: Oh and as always, if I answered your question correctly and don't need any further help, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Well, I still wanted to see some dnx vs dnxcore benchmarks :)

Comment: For me dnxcore on linux is ~4x faster that dnx451 on mono

Comment: @Chris The guys at Microsoft are spending a whole bunch of effort to make sure that string manipulation, comparison and others are as fast as the Windows implementation. I don't think the mono developers have the same resources. ;-)

Comment: The Mono libs including string were good it was there jit and gc that was rather poor. I had a look at it once for a security change and it had no updates in 7 years.